# What is difference between S3 and EMRFS?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hdfs, amazon-emr

I don't understand subtle difference between S3 and EMRFS. Should we treat EMRFS as a collection of libraries and APIs which allow to write/read to/from S3 from Hadoop applications or is it something more? And [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-file-systems.html) official doc does not help also.

Answer (score 8):

EMRFS is a library that implements hadoops FileSystem api.  EMRFS makes S3 look like hdfs or the local filesystem.  This is then used by many of the applications in the hadoop ecosystem such as spark and hive.  For example this is how you would use EMRFS to read from S3 in spark

```
val df = spark.read.parquet("S3://s3-bucket/path/to/folder/")
df.write.csv("s3://s3-bucket/path/to/output/")
```

Comment: Yes, I use it on a daily basis. But is it correct to name API as a File System.

Comment: In hadoop the class that is implemented is called "FileSystem".  In some cases it acts just like a file system in others it doesn't.

Answer (score -3):

The main advantage is consistency in emrfs. It internally uses Dynamo db to maintain consistency.